# .NET Core C# web API integration with ZOHO Books

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, accounting, zohobooks

How could I integrate my existing .Net Core application to ZOHO books for accounting and finance module.

Comment: Please share enough code.

Comment: please read this => https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/zoho-api-integration-inside-asp-net-application

Comment: also this => https://www.thecodehubs.com/zoho-crm-integration-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: see this also ==> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91a702a1-ef4a-4225-b8a8-6407542418b0/working-with-zoho-api-in-aspnet-c?forum=aspcomponetdiscussion